# cannot make cython vector of custom ctypedef class public

Tags: c++, python, vector, cython, public

I have class that has a c++ vector member holding custom class objects. I want to be able to read this vector as a list from python, but I have not been able to do it in any kind of way.

My headers:

```
from __future__ import division

import cython               
from libcpp.vector cimport vector   #this import the C++ vector, which
                                    #is compatible with python lists
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

#@cython.boundscheck(False) #this line remove some correct checking for
                            #for bounds, which makes it hard to debug
                            #but also faster
```

Here's is my custom class:

```
ctypedef class boid:
    """Placeholder for the boids"""
    cdef public vector[double] pos  #position of the boid
    cdef public vector[double] vel  #velocity of the boid

    def __init__(self, vector[double] pos_):
        self.pos = pos_
```

This is the other class, having the vector.

```
cdef class csopsim:
    """This is the simulation"""
    #declaring c variable types
    cdef vector[boid] boids  #list of boids

    def __init__(self,int scenario):
        #setting default values
        self.BOX_SIZE = 640
        self.BOX = float(self.BOX_SIZE)

        self.NUM_MALES = 10
        for x in xrange(self.NUM_MALES):
            self.boids.push_back(boid(0,np.random.uniform(350,450,2)))
```

This compiles nicely, but obviously trying to get csopsim.boids throws a no attribute error. If I modify it as

```
cdef public vector[boid] boids
```

it doesn't compile. If I create a method

```
def getboids(self):
    return self.boids
```

it doesn't compile. If I create a method

```
cdef vector[boid] getboids(self):
    return self.boids
```

it compiles, but when I try to call the method from python it throws an AttributeError: 'csopsim.csopsim' object has no attribute 'getboids'. I hope there's a simple and trivial solution to this problem:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used cythonizing a pure c++ class instead, as that seemed to work and is a bit more straightforward.